# Napoleon Gas fireplace GDS28N - why does pilot turn off when I turn main. burner off

Tags: fireplace, pilot-light

I have Napoleon gas stove fireplace GDS28N. The pilot on it stays lit when I have the valve position to PILOT. It also stays lit when I turn to valve to ON but have the main burner switch OFF.
However, when I use the fireplace with main burners ON and then switch it OFF, the pilot goes out few minutes after turning the switch OFF. What could be wrong here? I have vacuumed and cleaned the fireplace and the pilot. Coincidentally, this issue started to happen around the same time when my ignitor died. Not sure if it is related

Comment: is it manual ignitor or electric

Comment: Off is to turn everything off.  You have pilot and on for it to work.

Comment: It is manual ignitor. By off, I mean turning the switch off to turn off the main burners. The valve position stays ON. The pilot stays lit for few minutes after the main buners are turned off and then it goes off as well. I hear a click from the valve.

Comment: Check and clean the thermocouple that is used to report the flame is on